# How would Google give visual indicators for few search results?

Tags: google-search

I have searched on this for while with no luck. So asking here.
When I search for a few topics, Google would include ratings in some cases, author images in some cases, but in most cases, just text. In this case, IMDB got a star rating  in the results, but that does not happen to all rating sites, I suppose.
[image]

Is there something we can do to our site or is that what Google does only after a web site earns trust and are hugely popular?
How does it work with other search engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google calls these *Rich Snippets*.

Documentation: [About rich snippets and structured data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en)

Google supports three syntaxes which you can use to semantically annotate your content:

- [Microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML%29)
- [Microformats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat)
- [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa)

(For Microdata and RDFa you’d usually have to use the **Schema.org** vocabulary.)

Note that it doesn't necessarily have an effect for *all* sites that annotate their markup; Google (their algorithms) still decides whose search results will be enhanced.

Answer (score 0):

I think the devs a Google decide what sites are important enough to have their own feature, but Duckduckgo free to use zero-click-api does this great => https://duckduckgo.com/?q=terminator+judgement+day

Comment: What great is it doing? Its not showing ratings of that movie in search results from movie rating sites.